# Xamarin Forms Prism DialogService show behind ModalNavigation

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I am using a custom DialogService, the problem I have is that I first show a page as a modal and when sending to display the DialogPage it is apparently not shown but it really is behind the model page.

Invocation of the modal page

```
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("ProfilePage", useModalNavigation: true);
```

Xaml CustomDialog

```
<ContentView  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
              prism:DialogLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, -1, -1"
             prism:DialogLayout.RelativeWidthRequest="0.60"
              BackgroundColor="White"
             x:Class="ComedorIndustrial.Prism.Views.MessageDialog">

    <Grid Padding="30,60">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Source="iconoError.png" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#ee3837" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource RobotoBold}" FontSize="30"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Message}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#bdbcc2" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="14" />
        <Button Text="Volver a intentar"
            Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"
            BackgroundColor="#ee3837" BorderRadius ="25"  TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Opacity="1" FontSize="12" Margin="0,15,0,0"
            Grid.Row="3"/>
    </Grid>

</ContentView>
```

Custom dialog invocation

```
   public static void ShowAlert(this IDialogService dialogService, string title, string message)
    {
                var parameters = new DialogParameters
        {
            { "title", title },
            { "message", message }
        };
        dialogService.ShowDialog("MessageDialog", parameters);
    }
```

EDIT:

> I have solved it!

Add the plugin: Prism.Plugin.Popups

And then add the following line of code in App.xaml.cs: `containerRegistry.RegisterPopupDialogService();`

The documentation is on the following page: 
[popups.prismplugins.com](https://popups.prismplugins.com/)

Regards!

Comment: Can you please confirm some additional info here... where exactly are you calling ShowAlert from?

Comment: Sure. I have a MasterDetailPage, in the master command to call the ProfilePage as Modal, then in the ProfilePageViewModel I execute a method to save the changes that the user has made to your profile (an api service is used), if the api serive returns false, I execute the method to show the DialogPage as indicated in the code. Regards

Comment: `if (!response.IsSuccess)
            {
                CustomDialog.ShowAlert(_dialogService, "Error", response.Message.ToString());
                return;
            }`

Comment: ok so to confirm here, the DialogService is called well after the Modal page is displayed and as part of a check when the user executes some command from that Modal page. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes. Its right.

Comment: @DanSiegel I'm having a similar issue - not sure if I should create a new post? I do a relative navigation with this command: `await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("RegistrationPage");` then when I try show the dialog it appears behind that page, i.e. if I navigate back with `await _navigationService.GoBackAsync();` then I see the popup. If I do an absolute navigation, then the popup shows up.

Comment: The solution above worked for me, but I'm wondering why the other plugins are necessary? (prism.plugins.popups & Rg.plugins.popups). Is it a bug or does the Prism documentation need to be updated?

Answer (score 2):

What you've described is a known bug in Prism 7.2. This issue is fixed in Prism 8, or as you've noted you can simply use the Prism.Plugin.Popups to use the PopupPage variant of the service.